# Sending binary data to a servlet

Tags: javascript, file-upload, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

I am trying send a file to a servlet.

```
function sendToServlet(){

var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].  
           createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);  
file.initWithPath("C:\\Documents and Settings\\me\\Meus documentos\\Downloads\\music.mp3"); 

var boundary = "--------------" + (new Date).getTime();

var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"]  
                       .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream);  
stream.init(file, 0x04 | 0x08, 0644, 0x04); // file is an nsIFile instance     


// Send      
var req = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]  
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);  
req.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/app/server'  , false); 
var contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
req.send(stream);  

}
```

The source of javascript: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Sending_binary_data

But does not work.

Hi, this the serlevt code used:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         int size = 1024*20000;  
         long sizeFile = 0;
         File savedFile = null;      

         boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
         if (!isMultipart) {
         } else {
               FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
               ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
               upload.setFileSizeMax(new Long("-1"));
               List items = null;
               try {
                   items = upload.parseRequest(request);
               } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               Iterator itr = items.iterator();
               while (itr.hasNext()) {
               FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();

                   try {

                       if (item.isFormField()) {
                            ;
                       }else{

                           String itemName = item.getName();
                           int sizeName = itemName.length();
                           int end  = itemName.indexOf('\n');
                           int start = itemName.lastIndexOf('\\');
                           itemName = itemName.substring(start + 1, sizeName-end-1);

                           savedFile = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\eric.silva\\Meus documentos\\"+itemName);
                           item.write(savedFile);  
                       }                       

                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
    }//metodo
```

But when i try to send a file the servlet dont create the file sent.
Quando eu tento enviar via javascript a requisição é enviada. Mas o arquivo não é criado no lado do servidor. Acredito que o código apresentado no site da MDN esteja incompleto.

When I try to send via javascript the request is sent. But the file is not created on the server side. I believe the code shown on the site of the MDN is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note how the example code you are using is sending data with method `PUT` - valid `multipart-formdata` request needs to have some additional headers, not only the file itself. For example, the file you are sending should have a name (normally the name of the form field). You should [use a `FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_FormData_objects) instead, it will generate a valid request automatically. You should be able to [create a `File` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code) directly. Something along these lines:

```
var file = File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\me\\Meus documentos\\Downloads\\music.mp3");
var data = new FormData();
data.append("file", file);
var req = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]  
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);  
req.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/app/server', false);
request.send(data);
```

Note that creating `File` objects like this is only supported starting with Firefox 6.

Comment: Hi Wladimir, when I poaste this code into my addon (main.js), after converting to Chrome-Auth style (Cc, Ci etc.) it gives me "File is not defined, referring to the first line in your code. 

How do I use that in my main.js?

Comment: @Bora: Yes, the `File` constructor isn't defined in the context of the Add-on SDK modules. You have to "steal" it from some context, e.g. like that: `var {File} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", null);`

Comment: I just found out, that there is a `wrapDOMFile` method of the `nsIDOMWindowUtils` object, which does exactly what I need. Stealing is obviously another viable solution.

Comment: Also, there is an optional third parameter to the FormData.append() method, which accepts the file name, provided it is a File or Blob.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies more likely in how you're trying to obtain the uploaded file with the servlet. Being a low level impelementation, the servlet doesn't have much of an abstraction for handling uploaded files (multi part requests). Luckily there are libraries who take care of that for you like commons.FileUpload:

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

Just set up a servlet with fileUpload like it sais in the doc, then make a simple html page with a form that has a file upload input, and use that as a basic functional test to see that it works, then return to making your own client.