# How to upload binary content with Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

In my Firefox extension I download the file, then the extension should upload it. I do the following -

```js
// downloading file
var persist = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"]
                .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
              .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
              .get("TmpD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
file.append("temp.torrent");
file.createUnique(Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0666);

var fURI = synoext.srv.io.newURI(url,null,null);
  const nsIWBP = Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist;
  const flags = nsIWBP.PERSIST_FLAGS_REPLACE_EXISTING_FILES;
  persist.persistFlags = flags | nsIWBP.PERSIST_FLAGS_FROM_CACHE;
persist.progressListener = {
  onProgressChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aCurSelfProgress, aMaxSelfProgress, aCurTotalProgress, aMaxTotalProgress) {
    },
  onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
    if (aStateFlags & Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP) {
      // file has been downloaded, upload it 
      Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
      NetUtil.asyncFetch(file, function(inputStream, status) {
        if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
          return;
        }

        var filedata = NetUtil.readInputStreamToString(inputStream, inputStream.available());
        var boundary = "-----------------------ZzzZzzZzz";

        var postdata = "--"+boundary+"\r\n";
        postdata += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api\""+"\r\n";
        postdata += "\r\n";
        postdata += "SYNO.DownloadStation.Task"+"\r\n";

        postdata += "--"+boundary+"\r\n";
        postdata += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"version\""+"\r\n";
        postdata += "\r\n";
        postdata += "1"+"\r\n";

        postdata += "--"+boundary+"\r\n";
        postdata += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"method\""+"\r\n";
        postdata += "\r\n";
        postdata += "create"+"\r\n";

        postdata += "--"+boundary+"\r\n";
        postdata += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+file.leafName+"\""+"\r\n";
        postdata += "Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent"+"\r\n";
        postdata += "\r\n";
        postdata += filedata;
        postdata += "--"+boundary;
        postdata += "\r\n";

        var req = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                            .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
        req.open('POST', "http://192.168.1.5:5000/webapi/DownloadStation/task.cgi", true); // asynch
        req.onload = function() {
          // file uploaded
        };

        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
        // req.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', postdata.length);
        req.send(postdata);
      });
```

But the file uploaded incorrectly. Original file in my test case is 31Kb, but uploaded file is 46Kb. If I check `filedata.length`, then it is correct - 31Kb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create the POST body yourself, instead use the FormData object.

```js
var formData = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/files/formdata;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMFormData);
formData.append(key, value);

formData.append("file", File(file));
```

Comment: OK, but original question remains - how to pass nsiFile there? [The doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) says nothing about it.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I did yesterday. But is it cross-platform approach? Users started to complain that my extension with this code doesn't work on Mac.

Comment: Hi @paa , helped very much with the formData example. But, why do you use `File(file)` around an object "file" already of type `nsiFile` ?

Comment: FormData works with Blobs. File provides the suitable wrapper (nsIDOMFile, which inherits from nsIDOMBlob) around nsIFile

Comment: @paa How do I use it in my main.js? When I enter it like this, it gives me an error. ("File undefined")

Comment: You get this error because main.js runs in a restricted context, compared to traditional (xul) extensions.

Comment: @Bora, I was wrong. You can reach the `File` constructor from main.js

var {getMostRecentBrowserWindow} = require("window/utils");
var browser = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
var myfile = browser.File(whatever);

Comment: @paa Thanks for the commentl. See my comment in Wladimir's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532226/sending-binary-data-to-a-servlet).