# XMLHttpRequest POST and open target page in new window/tab

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

How do you emulate Form's `'POST'` action with `target="_blank"` in `XMLHttpRequest`? (ie post data and open target page in a new tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gBrowser` offers this functionality right out of the box.

```js
var dataStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIStringInputStream);
dataStream.data = "foo=bar&alpha=beta"; // make sure the values are properly encoded with encodeURIComponent

var postStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/mime-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIMIMEInputStream);
postStream.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
postStream.addContentLength = true;
postStream.setData(dataStream);

gBrowser.loadOneTab("http://www.example.com/", {inBackground: false, postData: postStream});
```

Comment: Great :) .... I am going to try it. Regarding `dataStream.data`, how can I pass a local file ie `'file:///C:/.../root.png'`?

Comment: Very useful stuff thanks man. Submitting files with this method would be nice too! By `values` being properly encoded you mean like: `dataStream.data = encodeURIComponent("foo")  + "=" + encodeURIComponent("ba-%r") + "&" + encodeURIComponent("@find") + "=" + encodeURIComponent("ba+$@r");` right?

Comment: @erosman try to [use FormData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900527/how-to-upload-binary-content-with-firefox-extension) and pass that as postStream, though I don't know if that will work with `loadOneTab`.